# Access Session on End?

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout

I am trying to "log" forcefully when a user has been inactive and or the session has ended (either by inactivity or more importantly, when the browser has closed).
I dont want to use any silly AJAX solution to perform a post every few minutes for "im alive" or call when the browser is closed.

I was under the impression that if you store an object in Session, and you reach the Session_End event, then you will not be able to gain access to anything stored in Session as its ended.
But from some testing I have done, it appears that this is probably the last chance you can obtain access to the object.

Could this be true? is it reliable?

using ASP.NET 4.0 here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For logging the timeout You can use the Global events to log at timeout. See this link for order of events http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/5771721

Comment: Thanks but you have completely misunderstood the question. I dont want to use any javascript timers, nor was I asking anything in relation to altering the session/forms auth timeout properties in the config

Comment: sorry just relized that after i posted. see revised answer

Answer (score 3):

Typically there are two things done.

The first is that a javascript timer is added to the client, not as a heartbeat, but rather as a reminder.  If they are close to the session ending, then it simply says "session is about to end.  Are you still there?"  If so, then it does the "silly" post to ensure the server keeps the session going.  This is purely to be nice to your users.

The second (and point of your question) is that you put something in session_end in order to clean up the session.  Reliable? well.. *most* of the time.

Session_End won't run if the app pool is recycled.  However, assuming the app pool is ok then yes it will execute when the session expires.  The app pool can be recycled for a LOT of reasons ranging from the app crashing to exceeded memory usage to simply because it's been a while since the last reset.  This is configurable in IIS.

Would I trust session_end?  No.  Not 100%.  Of course, I wouldn't put anything inside of a session object that would require me to trust it 100% anyway.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Hmm. I dont want to use any javascript hacks or callbacks. must be done at the server end completely if possible. What way is there for me to "close off" a user in session? I want to log the time the user logged off (apart from when they hit log off. When the session has ended). Having a script run in the backend to check every so often does not give you indication if there has been activity on the site or not for a user.

Comment: Really, all you can do is *hope* session_end actually runs.  For those cases when it doesn't you'll need a cleanup procedure server side that marks the users as logged out.  In order to support that you'll need to log every single time they do a page load or other action on your site in order to make sure that you don't log people off that are actively using the site.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I mean, from the test I did - I had Session expire every minute. I store a userID in session. I play around the site for more than a minute and session does not end. When I stop playing around and that minute mark hits, Session_End kicks in and I am able to access UserID in session. I can then do what i want here (i.e clean up). But for those cases where session_end does not hit, I guess I could run a SQL Job daily to update the "loggedOffAt" field from the time they logged in + x minutes. Thoughts on this?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas: That is exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Thought as much. Thanks Chris.